# PHP namespaces trouble

Tags: php

I just wanna use a namespace in another file, to use the class in it, but im too retarded to do this...

first file:

```
namespace fun;
use fun\kjr\trouble;

$trouble = new trouble('http://someURL');
```

second file:

```
namespace fun\kjr;

class trouble { ... }
```

This is the error i get:

```
Error: Fatal error: Class 'fun\kjr\trouble' not found in D:\wamp\www\fun\index.php on line 8
```

Where did I declare a wrong namespace? Oo

Greetings

Comment: Your second file doesn't contan valid code.

Comment: Neither is there any reference to `ReadRSS`

Comment: Sry, there's alot more in it, but I think only that part is needed to find the error^^ sorry

Comment: what is in your index.php on line 8 ?

Comment: Ow sure we don't need the actual problem part... We will just guess and make shit up

Comment: Are you using some kind of autoloading? If not, did you include the file? Autoloading isn't "auto" unless an appropriate loader is defined.

Comment: Lol honestly, @PeeHaa

this isnt a problem of content, but of the namespaces

Comment: I just got these two files at the moment, no framework nothing

Comment: but when i "use" the other class, i have access to its classes, or am i wrong oo?

Comment: @Xatenev : Can you just delete your "namespace fun;" in the first.

OR

use \kjr; instead of \fun\kjr

I guess PHP compiler wants to search your class in fun\fun\kjr

Comment: @Xatenev Nope. The `use` makes the class available in the current namespace without prefixing its own namespace, but does not `include/require` the file. You have to do that yourself (or let your autoloader do it)

Comment: @Xatenev Then you need to include the file. Autoloading can load files automatically based on the namespaces used. Without it, you have to do it manually.

Comment: ok thanks, normally i am working with frameworks like symfony2 or zend, who do all that automatically for me x) thanks!

Comment: Somebody write an answer, so we can close this^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (from what I can see) is you haven't specified an autoloader (e.g. with `spl_autoload_register()`) or haven't included the file in your code.  The `use` statement will only find a class for you if you have an autoloader in place, otherwise you must include your code ahead of time with `include`/`include_once` or `require`/`require once`.

I would start with making [an autoloader and registering it](https://www.yahoo.com/tech/the-heartbleed-aftermath-drags-on-what-passwords-you-82296501283.html) and then it may be wise to map your namespaces to directory structure as specified by [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

Answer (score 1):

I had to include my class aswell.

```
use namespace
```

only makes the class available in the actual context.

It does NOT include it, so you can cause it.

use

```
include_once('your.file')
```

to do that!

Thanks @Michael Berkowski for helping.